# Escape Variables with Printf

Tags: go

If I wanted to do the following:

```
fmt.Printf("Escape this -> %v... Do not escape this -> %v", "Unescaped")
```

How could I escape the first occurrence of `%v`?

`\%v` doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can use %% for literal %

```
%%  a literal percent sign; consumes no value
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/